# SQL can't get the accurate data

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, erd

I get trouble when getting data in SQL. How to have one table source or primary key but two different foreign key.

[This is the ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktK6b.png)
[This is the result but when i put the Departure it will be vice versa](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kefD0.png)

Comment: Totally unclear what you are asking.  Please edit your question, and show sample input, output, along with the query from your screen capture.

Comment: please check this link(https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to know more on how to ask/improve your question

Comment: You can have as many joins in your query as you like. If you want data from three tables then you need at least two joins. Do some appropriate research on joins and then, if you still need help, provide a FULL and CLEAR description of the problem.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the pictures already indicated, click the caption

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use table alias names for the table that is used twice, then join to it twice.

```
SELECT Routes.ID, DEP.IATACode, ARR.IATACode
FROM dbo.Routes
INNER JOIN dbo.Airports AS DEP ON DEP.ID = Routes.DepartureAirportID
INNER JOIN dbo.Airports AS ARR ON ARR.ID = Routes.ArrivalAirportID
```

You use the alias everywhere in the query once defined. See [here for more on using an alias](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Thank you so much i applied it in schedule table and it works! Merry Christmas

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, it seems that you're trying to get both the "Departure" and "Arrival" values from the same join. In order to get this to work, you'd need to have two separate joins from Routes to Airports (and aliased accordingly) for each of "Departure" and "Arrival".

```
select date, 
    time, 
    ArrivalAirport.IATACode as Departure,
    DepartureAirport.IATACode as Arrival,
    FlightNumber,
    Aircrafts.Name,
    EconomyPrice,
    Schedules.ID
from Schedules
inner join [Routes] on Schedules.RouteID = [Routes].ID
inner join Aircrafts on Schedules.AircraftID = Aircrafts.ID
inner join Airports as ArrivalAirport on ArrivalAirport.ID = [Routes].ArrivalAirportID
inner join Airports as DepartureAirport on DepartureAirport.ID = [Routes].DepartureAirportID
```

Note that the two instances of "Airports" joins necessitate the need to alias them accordingly so you can do what you need in the select projection.

Comment: All column references should have either their table name or table alias (if alias has been defined)

Comment: @PEBKAC It says "The multi-part identifier 'Airports.ID' could not be found "

Comment: @Christian Lumugdan ... corrected joins. Try it again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I think you are looking for:

```
SELECT
    Schedules.Date,
    Schedules.Time,
    DepartureAirport.IATACode AS Departure,
    ArrivalAirport.IATACode AS Arrival,
    Schedules.FlightNumber,
    Aircrafts.Name,
    Schedules.EconomyPrice,
    Schedules.ID
FROM
    Schedules
    INNER JOIN Aircrafts ON Schedules.AircraftID = Aircrafts.ID
    INNER JOIN Routes ON Schedules.RouteID = Routes.ID
    INNER JOIN Airports AS DepartureAirport 
            ON Routes.DepartureAirportID = DepartureAirport.ID
    INNER JOIN Airports AS ArrivalAirport
            ON Routes.ArrivalAirportID = DepartureAirport.ID
```

The thing is to have two separate joins onto the Airports table so you can have two different airports. Otherwise you will have very short flights, and very dissatisfied passengers.

Comment: I will try this

Comment: No data result.

Comment: No data result.